# Covariance not working with generic dictionary entry

Tags: c#, generics, covariance

Given the class below:

```
public class ConcreteEmployeeRoleCreator<T, TConcrete, TSpec> 
    where TConcrete : class, T, new()
    where T : EmployeeRole
    where TSpec : EmployeeRoleSpecification
{
    public ConcreteEmployeeRoleCreator(TSpec spec) { Specification = spec; }

    public TSpec Specification { get; private set; }

    public T Create() { return new TConcrete(); }

}
```

I would like to have a dictionary of 'creators', but I haven't been able to work out how to do it yet. If I try and define the dictionary using the lowest common denominator types, the compiler is not allowing an instance to be added

```
[Test]
public void Creator_CanCreateFromSpec() {
    var creators = new Dictionary<string, ConcreteEmployeeRoleCreator<EmployeeRole, EmployeeRole, EmployeeRoleSpecification>>();
    var spec = new SalesmanRoleSpecification();
    var creator = new ConcreteEmployeeRoleCreator<EmployeeRole, Salesman, SalesmanRoleSpecification>(spec);
    creators.Add("salesman", creator); <==== ** compile error **
}
```

Salesman *is* an EmployeeRole, and SalesmanRoleSpecification *is* an EmployeeRoleSpecification (or I wouldn't be able to define the creator above without a compiler error as well).

SO I guess it is the way I am declaring the dictionary? What am I doing wrong?

Cheers,
Berryl

Comment: Are you using C# 3.5 or 4.0? They made some improvements in C# 4.0

Comment: but what compiler says actually ?

Comment: Variance only applies (but not limited) to interfaces, _not_ concrete implementations.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generic covariance has to be specified at the declaration of the covariant type - and it can *only* be specified for interfaces and delegates.

So, given that you're using a class, a

```
ConcreteEmployeeRoleCreator<EmployeeRole, Salesman, SalesmanRoleSpecification>
```

will never be a

```
ConcreteEmployeeRoleCreator<EmployeeRole, EmployeeRole, EmployeeRoleSpecification>
```

You'll need to look for an alternative approach. To be honest, by the time you get to three type parameters and want two of them to be covariant, you've got a pretty hard-to-understand design to start with, I'm afraid :(

Comment: I am actually relieved you put it that way! I am  trying to work thru a design on the "Role Object Pattern" by Baumer, Reihle in '97 where they use another pattern of theirs, "Product Trader" which had a c++ template that *seemed* to be equivalent of the generic class I came up with. I am hoping that if the paper were written today it would just use Activator.CreateInstance(Type) like I am doing now. Cheers